# Integrate twitter timeline using cordova 3.3.0

Tags: iframe, cordova, twitter

Is there any way to integrate twitter timeline widget using Cordova3.3.0 with iFrame??

We have already used -

https://github.com/k-rudy/phonegap-twitter-timeline

but it only works on android and other browsers but not on iPad/iPhone.

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this one!